# jsp & rich:dataTables logout when using images

Tags: jsp, jsf, richfaces

I've got a weired problem with a rich:dataTable:

My homepage project has some directories wich need authentification to access.
It done by form-based login. Works fine, as expected.

On one page is a rich:dataTable. Even here everything works.
But I have to login in again when i try to go to anohter page (within the same directory)
I the table i use the h:graphicImage tag :

```html
<rich:dataTable  id="stdlist" rowClasses="tbleven,tblodd" value="#{sbasSS.SMStatuslist}" var="loc" 
  columnClasses="centertd, centertd"
  headerClass="tblheader" reRender="true">
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header" >
            <h:outputText value="mobilnummer"/>
        </f:facet>    
        <h:outputText value="#{loc.destination}"/> 
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header" >
            <h:outputText value="lev. status"/>
        </f:facet>    
        <h:graphicImage value="/Teacher/flags/#{loc.status}.gif" />
    </rich:column>  
</rich:dataTable>
```

The images are shown as they should. No fail in the path or so. but i got thrown out and the session is invalidated.

If I change

```
<h:graphicImage value="/Teacher/flags/#{loc.status}.gif" />
```

into

```
<h:outputText value="#{loc.status}"/>
```

the expected text is shown. Navigation works. I don't have to  login again.

Any idea what this might be?

Best regards
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

Fact is, all URL references in a HTML document like images, scripts, CSS files, etc are each individually requested by a brand new and distinct HTTP request. The symptoms suggests that you've an overzealous authentication `Filter` in the webapp which isn't doing its job properly and for some reason invalidates the whole session once an image is requested.

That's all which can be told/guessed based on the information provided so far. Your next step would be to debug that filter and invest some more time in learning how HTML, HTTP and webbrowsers in general work. This problem has at least nothing to do with the RichFaces datatable. You'd surely have exactly the same problem when you have only a `<h:graphicImage>` with a hardcoded `#{loc.status}` value in the page.

Comment: That's whats confusing me: If I use a harcoded Imaga like `<h:graphicImage value="../include/flags/flag_d.gif" />` it works fine. And theres no filter defined i the application (Except for the org.ajax4jsf.filter)